# Implementing secret reconstruction in Shamir's Secret Sharing

Tags: implementation, secret-sharing

I am trying to implement Shamir's secret sharing in C++.
I have got the generation of shares working.

However, I am very confused with the reconstruction of shares. I get the part on how three users can reconstruct the secret. But what if there are more than 3 users needed to reconstruct the secret? How do I implement the formula then?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $s_0, s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_{k-1}$ are
elements from the finite field you are working in, where $s_0$ is the secret
to be shared, and the $s_i, i > 0$ are randomly chosen nonzero elements of
the field. Then, the polynomial used to construct the shares is
$$S(x) = s_0 + s_1x + s_2x^2+ \cdots + s_{k-1}x^{k-1}$$ and the shares
themselves are $y_i = S(x_i), 1 \leq i \leq n$ where the $x_i$ are
$n$ distinct nonzero elements of the field. Note that $n$ must be at least as
large as $k$, and that the polynomial $S(z)$ can be recovered
from any $k$ of these $n$ shares. This is commonly done using
Lagrange interpolation as has been already pointed out in the other
answers.  Assuming without loss of generality that $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_k$
are the shares available for reconstruction, $S(x)$ is a *weighted*
sum (or linear combination) of $k$ different
polynomials $g_i(x)$.  We have
$$\begin{align}
S(x) &= \sum_{i=1}^k y_i \cdot g_i(x)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k y_i \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^k\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}\\
&= y_1 \frac{(x-x_2)(x-x_3)\cdots(x-x_k)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)\cdots(x_1-x_k)}
+ y_2 \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_3)\cdots(x-x_k)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)\cdots(x_2-x_k)}\\
&\qquad 
+y_3 \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_4)\cdots(x-x_k)}{(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)(x_3-x_4)\cdots(x_3-x_k)}
+\cdots\\
&\qquad 
+y_k \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_{k-1})}{(x_k-x_1)(x_k-x_2)\cdots(x_k-x_{k-1})}
\end{align}$$
Notice that each $y_i$ is being multiplied by the polynomial
$$g_i(x) = \frac{1}{c_i}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_{i-1})(x-x_{i+1})\cdots(x-x_k)$$
which has as factors all terms of the form $(x-x_j)$ **except** $(x-x_i)$, and
the constant $c_i$ is given by
$$c_i = (x_i-x_1)(x_i-x_2)\cdots(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})\cdots(x_i-x_k).
\tag{1}$$
In other words, $g_i(x_i)=1$ and $g_i(x_j)=0$ for all $j \neq i$.

So there is a lot of calculation required, and care must be exercised
when writing the computer program that carries out these calculations.
But note that we *really don't need to compute* **the entire polynomial**
$S(z)$  since all we want to find is the secret $s_0 = S(0)$. This
saves us a fair amount of work because we have
$$\begin{align}
S(0) &= \sum_{i=1}^k y_i \cdot g_i(0)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^k y_i \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^k\frac{-x_j}{x_i-x_j}\\
&= y_1 \frac{(-x_2)(-x_3)\cdots(-x_k)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)\cdots(x_1-x_k)}
+ y_2 \frac{(-x_1)(-x_3)\cdots(-x_k)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)\cdots(x_2-x_k)}\\
&\qquad 
+y_3 \frac{(-x_1)(-x_2)(-x_4)\cdots(-x_k)}{(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)(x_3-x_4)\cdots(x_3-x_k)}
+\cdots\\
&\qquad 
+y_k \frac{(-x_1)(-x_2)\cdots(-x_{k-1})}{(x_k-x_1)(x_k-x_2)\cdots(x_k-x_{k-1})}\\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^k y_i \cdot (-1)^{k-1}\frac{x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_k}{x_i\cdot c_i}\\
s_0 &= (-1)^{k-1} (x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_k) \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{y_i}{x_i\cdot c_i}
\end{align}$$
So now the task seems a little easier. We need to
compute $x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_k$ only once using $k-1$ multiplications,
each $c_i$ has to be calculated separately and needs $k-1$ subtractions
and $k-2$ multiplications. We multiply $c_i$ by $x_i$ and *then*
do the division $y_i/(x_i\cdot c_i)$.  The hard part in all this is thus writing
the code for computing each $c_i$.  And of course we must remember that
all this is using finite-field arithmetic so that we must use operations
or subroutine calls as described in the answer by Ilmari Karonen.

Comment: @Mathys Thank you for your careful reading of my answer and correction of a typo that nobody else noticed for 11 years!

Answer (score 2):

The formula you are looking for is [Lagrange Basis Polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Essentially, each share consists of two values, an x coordinate and an y coordinate. The x coordinate might, depending on your specific needs, be implicitly determined by context, such as a preexisting identifier for the entity holding the share. The only requirement is that it is non-zero and unique. The y coordinate is calculated as the value of the polynomial (with random coefficients and a degree equal to the threshold parameter) in the x coordinate.

Hence, in pseudo code, in order to generate $n$ shares such that at least $m+1$ shares are required to regenerate the secret, and presuming you work in a $\mathbb Z_p$ field, do the following:

$Input: $ Parameters $n, m$. A large prime $p$. Secret $s$, represented as an element in $\mathbb Z_p$. Coordinates $x_0,...,x_{n-1}$.

$Setup:$

1. $c_0 = s$
2. For $i$ from 1 to $m$ do

   1. $c_i \leftarrow_{Uniform} \mathbb Z_p^*$
3. For $j$ from 0 to $n-1$ do

   1. $y_j = \Sigma_{i=0}^mc_ix_j^i$

You regenerate the secret $s$ from $k$ shares, such that $k \gt m$, by implementing the Lagrange Interpolation Polynomial $L(x)$ using the $x_j,y_j$ pairs you got access to, and calculating $s' = L(0)$.

As per your question, if $m = 2$ and $k = 3$ (presuming that $k = n$ for simplicity), the formula for $L(x)$ becomes:

$L(x) = y_0\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)} + y_1\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)} + y_2\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}$

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to reconstruct the secret is using [Neville's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm).

Basically, let the array `y` contain `n` shares (assumed to be represented as the type `gf_t` here), let the array `x` contain the points at which the polynomial was evaluated to generate those shares, and let `sub()`, `mul()` and `inv()` be functions/macros that perform the appropriate finite field subtraction, multiplication and inversion respectively.  Then the following function computes the value of the interpolated polynomial at zero:

```
gf_t shamir_reconstruct (int n, gf_t *x[], gf_t *y[]) {
    int d,i;
    for (d = 1; d < n; d++) {
        for (i = 0; i < n - d; i++) {
            int j = i + d;
            gf_t num = sub( mul( x[j], y[i] ), mul( x[i], y[i+1] ) );
            gf_t den = sub( x[j], x[i] );
            y[i] = mul( num, inv(den) );
        }
    }
    return y[0];
}
```

This code is written in C, but it should work with appropriate modifications in C++ too.  Note that this function overwrites the `y` array; if this is not desired, make a copy of it first.  Finally, note that I wrote this code off the top of my head — I haven't actually tested it.