# How to maximise compatibility of Shamir's Secret Sharing

Tags: secret-sharing

I want to create a shared secret from a short string (e.g. a password) which should be easy to decrypt also in the long term. Unfortunately, I have quite a hard time to make the different tools work with each other (e.g. encrypt with [ssss](http://point-at-infinity.org/ssss/) and decrypt using an online tool like [that](https://iancoleman.io/shamir/) one.)

1. How should one convert the string into a hex/int? Most tools have some `str2hex` methods implemented. But to maximise compatibility, it is probably best, to use one defined method for this conversion?
2. Which format of the key is most common? [ssss](http://point-at-infinity.org/ssss/) uses something like `<share-num>-<key>` where  simply counts from 1. The online tool I linked above does have seemingly arbitrary prefixes (e.g. `801` to `80n`)
3. As described in [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/105502/reference-implementation-of-shamirs-secret-sharing) post, there seems to be no 'reference' implementation. But which implementation is the most common and future proof?

---

Example:

I encrypted the simple message `hello world` with $n=3$ and $k=5$.
I get the following shares with different methods:

- *[online tool](https://iancoleman.io/shamir/)* (using [secrets.js](https://github.com/amper5and/secrets.js) in the backend):

```
801677cc787a261d8f85c21695ed7479db5a8c711db5be53f886353611e36a4a18885faac6325630566b1d0690242683a08f7ab08b43d88a035518381049a32e7d1c015548805580cd627a6a212092b6baf3a59b4375ef629686504d60831198e9605ea1e4a816ad7a02b57fa365abaf2b0504a80c548b2322bc9a8fb04cbcf8138

802a79ba64974e16330798f1bb91b40190ff56e0208703767fd54fd24f05b1053ae7fab8ee6774f00c07e84a27e577c3a368d9f531f8b8424fdc37219c826aa8924a3a38f6dc1321e574721036dfbec4770410023dff463d26d00a3593a34048656cb443eaa9f39e83dc8869df1def6a53990d999dc3202165a68f783aaeccd58ba

803c0e761ced680bbc825ae72e7cc0784ba5da913d32bd2587537ae45ee6db4f226fa512285522c05a6cf54cb7c1514003e7a345babb60c84c892f198ccbc986ef563b6dbe5c46a12816087a17ff2c72cdf7b5997e8aa95fb0565a78f32051d08c0ceae20e01e533f9de3d067a3842057fbc0fc196e7a90241ea13378c22767d9ea

804eaba85e75c53d933d110357bac9fcae32d0f84a6dfc9aa00da96f7ea6a2996f7435e0a511a8028adf8f18409c57251f4e254b78be80bb181025d2aaa70567a1ea3459f4794562411aa9f73e36817f02c56f2035dc8b483140fcd35dc2dd0372da88674b119e1bce7cfbeea9714e93a8bfdc90553d608f9cb6b7fa6a5448bb104

8058dc64260fe3201cb8d315c257bd8575685c8957d842c9588b9c596f45c8d377fc6a4a6323fe32dcb4921ed0b871a6bfc15ffbf3fd58311b453deabaeea649dcf6350cbcf910e28c78d39d1f1613c9b836cabb76a9642aa7c6ac9e3d41cc9b9bbad6c6afb988b6b47e4e810c54e3fc849adec85e19e9acb8fa2bb5dcd8f213054
```

- [ssss-split](http://point-at-infinity.org/ssss/) with a security level of `-s 1024`

```
1-fb7b07816f2939e51e0494f7434c814c5f915b456bcbe6847f4b25c86997b0d9493910593e02d73f597cb7baaa169e6e709bccf75ae109dd3d423846d277bedad105de8f8cfa4ea1440c4605befd7972886099091daec2dd7ca42de0747c2c4948b81faaba739772457ad9aea91dcb56aafe35b7b27e57a91450d24e3879adbb

2-10ede114c4320a7000bcfb640013659c83d3402bc1ff1c6b79e189a14e162ab7ca2c24a2ddf85cb0f6e1028ebf9b9467b41917731a15be9edb8d3daba2e146e525b681f5aa29a5c8fe470e1df0b7457b35b219bc52ba1033a5469b5146519a2290e49173a68fbc7492cd9ebd8281a56c785e220e1ab8e767d092a7cb6e22fac9

3-605e2829637d01aa1386dc882365aab75e718b2896260df53e8d5f0bb983625aa636a282f302f026938ddc168b766004bdf6ddd07c1888c42c9897c127b1691da5b5984b18d0dc056324ce37f424f5ac7e9412cea1390ad07b067d4b5b491deb2d250cc813363e6d3e5229c8eaafbb2b7948469256eca8ec2ed1c213bcafc873

4-548866a1dbe6fd4db9e23d793b7acf236b6729308eb600cf87d458bdc2d2505727d609a0c92dcd4ea951e40bfed6cc6b9964359dda908b061625206841301e756abf9c5fd13796d8e082b7d2202665d9ac4df17df945bf0e412e18d0631e3000463b0483559bf3e597eaf42509ee06254aee5f15c7e667e3870ef89d6468563b

5-243baf9c7ca9f697aad81a95180c0008b6c5e233d96f1151c0b88e17354718ba4bcc8f80e7d761d8cc3d3a93ca3b3808908bff3ebc9dbd5ce1308a02c460318deabc85e163ceef157de177f824b5d50ee76bfa0f0ac6a5ed9f6efeca7e06b7c9fbfa9938e02271fc3b75435061c018624bf83b898bb22868794d9d45b6e56493
```

- [pyseltounge](https://github.com/ginsburgnm/pyseltongue) with the `PlaintextToHexSecretSharer`:

```
f-2c9d7393bc96215d194b1
e-d1268921fa76f8cb67Aafa
d-b87637f53fbe31132fe68
c-913acb42Ad3ca172729e3a
b-82f14b7b6053c474e7cb41
```

I was not able to decrypt any of those shares with a different tool which makes the whole process more or less useless (if for example some tools do not work in the future anymore).

Do you have any tips, how I should process the messages for a maximum compatibility also in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is unlikely to dissapear or change to cause incompatibility. Old JS applications packaged as a single web page with all dependencies run just fine.

So consider turning the message into several `share.html` files. The file would contain the message share, some text boxes or a file upload form in which to paste additional shares and a copy of [secret.js](https://github.com/amper5and/secrets.js/blob/master/secrets.min.js).

As an alternative you could use a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). The bookmarklet can likely be small (300 chars maybe) and just prompt the user with some text alert boxes or something.

A little bit of extra work can turn the resulting web page into a [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) if you feel like getting fancy, allowing that page to spit out another set of secret shares for something else.